# module 'keras.layers.normalization' has no attribute 'BatchNormalizationBase'

Tags: python, auto-keras

when i run this code

```
 import os
 from autokeras import 
 StructuredDataClassifier
 import stellargraph as sg
 from stellargraph.mapper import 
 FullBatchNodeGenerator
 from tensorflow.keras import layers, 
 optimizers, losses, metrics, Model
 from sklearn import preprocessing, 
 model_selection
 from IPython.display import display, HTML
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 %matplotlib inline
```

i have this error

```
 AttributeError: module 'keras.layers.normalization' has no attribute 'BatchNormalizationBase'
```

Knowing that this code has been run many times without any problems

Comment: I have the same problem did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my case which had a structure like this:

[image]

I added these two lines to the`__init__.py` file:

```py
from keras.layers.normalization.layer_normalization import *
from keras.layers.normalization.batch_normalization import *
```

And problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

restart runtime then reinstall keras library